# I can display database that is sql in php, but i don't know how to use the php insert/update/delete

Tags: php, mysql

I have already to find many ways to try, but I cannot do the insert/update/delete.
I still find the ways, so I hope someone can help me. Thank You!

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '123456'); //The Blank string is the password
mysql_select_db('album');

$query = "SELECT * FROM property"; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "All property";
echo "<table>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
echo "<tr><td>" ." Update_date: ". $row['Update_date'] . "</td><td>" ." Region: " .$row['Region'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
echo "<tr><td>" ." Street: " . $row['Street'] . "</td><td>" ." Building: " . $row['Building'] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>" ." Unit: " . $row['Unit'] . "</td><td>";
echo "<tr><td>" ." Saleable_area: " . $row['Saleable_area']."</td><td>" ." Construction_area: " . $row['Construction_area'] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>" ." Rent: " . $row['Rent'] . "</td><td>" ." Price: $" . $row['Price'] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>" ." Contant_person: " . $row['Contant_person'] . "</td><td>" ." Contant_Num: " . $row['Contant_Num'] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>" ." Layout: " . $row['Layout'] . "</td><td>" ." Decoration: " . $row['Decoration'] . "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr> <td>"."<a href=\photo.php>Photo</a>"."<tD><tR>";
echo "<tr> <td>";
echo "<tr> <td>";
echo "<tr> <td>";
echo "<tr> <td>";
echo "<tr> <td>";
}

echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

mysql_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysql` is a deprecated extension. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. Here is an example of statements -

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
//insert
$mysqli->query("insert into yourtable (field_first, field_second) values ('valueFirst', 'valueSecond')");
//update
$mysqli->query("update yourtable set field_first='valueFirst' where id=2");
//delete
$mysqli->query("delete from yourtable where id = 2");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO property VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

**Note:** **Do not use mysql-* functions anymore as they are deprecated, better go for mysqli or PDO.**

for more references please follow http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Do not use mysql-* functions anymore as they are deprecated as @sgt points out

Comment: or you misspelled `mysqlI_query` :)

Answer (score 0):

**INSERT:**

```
$title=$_POST['title'] ;
        $author= $_POST['author'] ;                 
        $name=$_POST['name'] ;
        $copy=$_POST['copy'] ;

mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `example`(Title,Author,PublisherName,CopyrightYear) 
VALUES ('$title','$author','$name','$copy')");
```

**DELETE :**

```
$id =$_REQUEST['BookID'];
mysqli_query("DELETE FROM example WHERE BookID = '$id'")
```

**UPDATE**

```
$title_save = $_POST['title'];
$author_save = $_POST['author'];
$name_save = $_POST['name'];
$copy_save = $_POST['copy'];

mysqli_query("UPDATE example SET Title ='$title_save', Author ='$author_save',
 PublisherName ='$name_save',CopyrightYear ='$copy_save' WHERE BookID = '$id'")
```

Answer (score 0):

For Update you try...

```
    $query = "UPDATE property SET 
            `field_name1`='$update_value1', 
            `field_name2`='$update_value2'
             WHERE id=$id ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Insert Query**

```
$ins="INSERT INTO `your_table_name` (`field_name1`,`field_name2`) VALUES ('value1','value2')";
 $exe=mysql_query($ins);
```

**Update Query**

```
 $update="UPDATE `table_name` SET `field_name1`='val1',`field_name2`='val2' WHERE `place_your condition`";
 $exe_up=mysql_query($update);
```

**Delete Query**

```
 $delete="DELETE `tbl_name` WHERE `place_your condition`";
 $exe_del=mysql_query($delete);
```